# Switch between associatons in Sequelize (One To Many and Many to Many at the same time)

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have tables `User`, `Assignment`, `FavoriteAssignment`. `User` can create many `Assignment`s, which will be assigned only to him, i.e `one to many` associaton.
But many `User`s can add many `Assignment`s to their favorites, i.e `many to many` association through `FavoriteAssignment` table.

How can I include `User`'s created assignments or his favorite assignments? I mean how should I switch between associatons when making include using **sequelize**?

User's associations:

```
  class User extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      User.hasMany(models.Assignment, { foreignKey: 'authorTelegramId'});
      User.belongsToMany(models.Assignment, { through: 'FavoriteAssignments', foreignKey: 'telegramId'});
    }
  };
```

Assignment's associations:

```
  class Assignment extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      Assignment.belongsTo(models.User, {foreignKey: 'authorTelegramId'});
      Assignment.belongsToMany(models.User, {through: 'FavoriteAssignments', foreignKey: 'assignmentId'});
    }
  };
```

FavoriteAssignment's association:

```
  class FavoriteAssignment extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      FavoriteAssignment.belongsTo(models.User, {foreignKey: 'telegramId'});
      FavoriteAssignment.belongsTo(models.Assignment, {foreignKey: 'assignmentId'});
    }
  };
```

I came to this question, because when I do:

```
const result = await db.User.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: db.Assignment
    }]
});
```

It fetches all `User`'s favorite assignments, as `belongsToMany` was defined last!
If I comment `User.belongsToMany(models.Assignment, { through: 'FavoriteAssignments', foreignKey: 'telegramId'});` line, then it will fetch all `User`'s created assignments (`one to many` association).

How can I **choose** which association I want to use, if I have more than one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I had to name associations like this:

```
  User.hasMany(models.Assignment, { foreignKey: 'authorTelegramId', as: 'assignments'});
  User.belongsToMany(models.Assignment, { through: 'FavoriteAssignments', foreignKey: 'telegramId', as: 'favoriteAssignments'});
```

And then call it:

```
const result = await db.User.findAll({
    include: ['assignments']
});
const result1 = await db.User.findAll({
    include: ['favoriteAssignments']
});
```